# Does subprocess.communicate() close stdin after writing input to it?

Tags: python, subprocess

While it would seem logical, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) does not explicitly state it:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the source I think the answer is yes:

- when timeout is None, `communicate()` calls `self._stdin_write(input)`
  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L826-L827
- otherwise `_communicate()` calls `self._stdin_write(input)`
  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L1078-L1079
- in each case `_stdin_write()` calls `self.stdin.close()` after `self.stdin.write(input)`
  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L793

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should I suggest an addition to the docs? Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Presumably [this docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L803-L813) would be changed by [Submitting a Patch](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/05/22/core-python-development-how-to-submit-a-patch/)

Comment: Done! https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/3533 . Not sure how far it will go, contributing to python is a bit daunting...