# want to provide input to child process without using communicate python

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio, child-process

basically i am writing a script to automate a process , in script i pass a command which creates a child processes (parallely) and my script does not have control over that child process. i want to provide a series of input to the child process and then wait for it to end.

a dummy code for what i want to do:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('python3', stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    
    print('hi1')
    
    process.stdin.write("import time \nprint('whatsup') \nfo = open('foo.txt', 'w') \nfo.write('Python is a great language.') \nfo.close() \ntime.sleep(3) \nprint('yo')".encode("utf-8"))
    
    print('end')
    
    await process.wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

the program never ends in my case

couldnt find a better way to communicate with the child process

Answer (score 2):

what works is to do

```
process.stdin.close()
```

before the `await` call.

Full code that works for me (replaced `python3` by `py`, which is the python startup on windows for me)

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('py', stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    print('hi1')

    process.stdin.write("import time \nprint('whatsup') \nfo = open('foo.txt', 'w') \nfo.write('Python is a great language.') \nfo.close() \ntime.sleep(3) \nprint('yo')".encode("utf-8"))

    print('end')
    process.stdin.close()
    await process.wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

output

```
hi1
end
whatsup
yo
```

and the `foo.txt` file is created.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46192336/6451573) has analyzed python source code for `communicate` and it seems that it also closes standard input to make it work.

> in each case _stdin_write() calls self.stdin.close() after self.stdin.write(input)
> https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L793

I don't remember where I learned that trick myself or why it is needed but that solves it. The limitation is that you cannot send multiple separate commands that way and interact with the process.

Comment: thanks a lot @jean , i already figured this out , but i wanted to know what if i want to write again to the child process, if i close the pipe that wont be possible right

Comment: ErykSun (great process & windows expert) comments on that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910789/how-to-open-closed-stdin-subprocess-again, it doesn't look trivial, no.

Comment: again thanks a lot for answering my doubt @jean, can you suggest a better way to send inputs to child process , where i can right multiple time and have a better contol over child process

Comment: a lot of people do that with sockets by sending UDP packets with commands in them. More complex to set up, but not limited like the stdin method